# Получить значения нескольких столбцов с одинаковыми названиями из разных таблиц

Tags: sql

Друзья, вопрос вроде бы элементарный, но чего-то сильно туплю, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.
Есть 2 таблицы gaz и svet c такими данными:
|id|date|value|

Мне нужно получить из этих таблиц ВСЕ значения date и value. 
Можно, конечно, двумя запросами к БД. 
Здесь без проблем, все в порядке, но как это сделать одним запросом?
Вот такой запрос не подходит:

```
select
  gaz.date as date1, gaz.value as value1,
  svet.date as date2 , svet.value as value2
from gaz, svet
```

т.к. в итоге date1 и date2 содержат даты из обеих таблиц, также как value1 и value2 содержат значения из обеих таблиц. Мне нужно получить данные в таком формате:
date1 - даты только из первой таблицы, date2 - даты только из второй таблицы
аналогично с value1 и value2.
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Дополняю вопрос.
Описанный мною запрос выводит следующие данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в каждой таблице только по 2 записи (сделал для удобства), а выводятся по 4, т.е. в каждый результат записываются данные из обоих таблиц, а мне нужно следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иными словами, date1 - даты только из таблицы gaz, date2 - только из таблицы svet, аналогично с value1 и value2.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо з рекомендацию. Попробовал select
  gaz.date as date1, gaz.value as value1 from gaz
  UNION ALL
    select
  svet.date as date2 , svet.value as value2
from svet, получаю 2 колонки date1 и value1 в которых содержатся данные из обоих таблиц без разделения

Comment: Дополните вопрос примером данных и примером желаемого вывода запроса. Макс. 3-и строки в обоих таблицах будет достаточно.

Comment: Обновил информацию. Спасибо.

Comment: Нумеруете записи в каждой таблице, затем соединяете их по равенству номеров (full join).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Если не сложно, пример кода.